# Does changing control of an object update that object's timestamp?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This is a follow-up question to [does gaining control of an aura gaining control of a permanent give me the permanent?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/34398/does-gaining-control-of-an-aura-gaining-control-of-a-permanent-give-me-the-perma)

1. Player A has a creature.
2. Player B casts [Control Magic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bControl%20Magic%5d) on it. B controls the creature.
3. Player C also casts Control Magic on it. C controls the creature due to the enchantments' timestamps.
4. Player D casts [Steal Enchantment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSteal%20Enchantment%5d) on player B's Control Magic.

Does player D or C now control the creature now? Player C's Control Magic is more recent, but does B's Control Magic timestamp get updated because of Steal Enchantment?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Player C controls it

> 613.6a A continuous effect generated by a static ability has the same timestamp as the object the static ability is on, or the timestamp of the effect that created the ability, whichever is later.
>
> 613.6c An object receives a timestamp at the time it enters a zone.

Even though you gain control of it it stays in the same zone, the battlefield, but it is an aura so there are more rules to it

> 613.6d An Aura, Equipment, or Fortification receives a new timestamp at the time it becomes attached to an object or player.

But it is still enchanting the same creature so it does not receive a new timestamp meaning player c still controls it